# Java project returning null values

Tags: java, eclipse, null, project, zero

Hi I am new to Java programming. Why are my values returning null after I enter them on the input dialog. I have two classes, one called VehicleApp and the other called VehicleFactory. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

### Full code  VehicleApp.java

```
package romprojectname;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class VehicleApp{

public static void main(String[] args) {

        String firstname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your first name");
        String lastname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your last name");
        long phone = Long.parseLong(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your phone"));
        int nbrVehicles = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of vehicles"));
        int nbrTanks = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of tanks"));

        VehicleFactory vehicleObject = new VehicleFactory();
        vehicleObject.getSummary();
        vehicleObject.HayloFactory(firstname, lastname, phone, nbrVehicles, nbrTanks);
        vehicleObject.calcFuelTankCost();
        vehicleObject.calcManufacturingCost();
        vehicleObject.calcSubtotal();
        vehicleObject.calcTax();
        vehicleObject.calcTotal();
    }
    }
```

### Full code VehicleFactory.java

```
package romprojectname;

   import java.text.NumberFormat;
   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

   public class VehicleFactory{
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Long phone;
    private int nbrVehicles =0;
    private int nbrTanks =0;
    private double manufactureCost =0;
    private double fuelTankCost =0;
    private double subtotal =0;
    private double tax =0;
    private double total = 0;
    private final double VEHICLE_PRICE = 500.19;
    private final double FUELCELL_PRICE = 2.15;
    private final int CELLS_PER_TANK = 12;
    private final double taxrate = 7.25 / 100 ;

public void HayloFactory(String firstname, String lastname, Long phone, int nbrVehicles, int nbrTanks){
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.nbrVehicles = nbrVehicles;
    this.nbrTanks = nbrTanks;
}

public void calcManufacturingCost(){
    double manufactureCost = nbrVehicles * VEHICLE_PRICE;
}

public void calcFuelTankCost(){
    double fuelTankCost = nbrVehicles * nbrTanks * CELLS_PER_TANK * FUELCELL_PRICE;
}

public void calcSubtotal(){
    double subtotal = manufactureCost + fuelTankCost;
}

public void calcTax(){
    double tax = subtotal * taxrate;
}

public void calcTotal(){
    double total = subtotal + tax;
}   

NumberFormat cf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

public void getSummary(){
    String summary = "WELCOME TO HAYLO MANUFACTURING" + "\n" + "\n";

    summary += "Customer Name: " + firstname + " " + lastname + "\n";
    summary += "Customer Phone: " + phone + "\n";
    summary += "Number of Vehicles: " + nbrVehicles + "\n";
    summary += "Number of Tanks: " + nbrTanks + "\n";
    summary += "Vehicle Cost ($500.19 / vehicle): " + cf.format(manufactureCost) + "\n";
    summary += "Tanks Cost ($2.15 / fuel cell): " + cf.format(fuelTankCost) + "\n";
    summary += "Subtotal: " + cf.format(subtotal) + "\n";
    summary += "Tax (7.25%): " + cf.format(tax) + "\n";
    summary += "Total: " + cf.format(total) + "\n";

    //display the summary
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, summary);
            }  
    }
```

### Problem (code taken from VehicleFactory.java)

All of the summaries such as customer name are returning null values and all the costs and totals are $0.00.

```
public void getSummary(){
String summary = "WELCOME TO HAYLO MANUFACTURING" + "\n" + "\n";

summary += "Customer Name: " + firstname + " " + lastname + "\n";
summary += "Customer Phone: " + phone + "\n";
summary += "Number of Vehicles: " + nbrVehicles + "\n";
summary += "Number of Tanks: " + nbrTanks + "\n";
summary += "Vehicle Cost ($500.19 / vehicle): " + cf.format(manufactureCost) + "\n";
summary += "Tanks Cost ($2.15 / fuel cell): " + cf.format(fuelTankCost) + "\n";
summary += "Subtotal: " + cf.format(subtotal) + "\n";
summary += "Tax (7.25%): " + cf.format(tax) + "\n";
summary += "Total: " + cf.format(total) + "\n";

//display the summary
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, summary);
```

Comment: Which values? Please give more context - and ideally cut the code down to just a very short example which reproduces the problem. (One troublesome field would be ample...)

Answer (score 3):

You haven't really described the problem, but I suspect this is the cause:

```
VehicleFactory vehicleObject = new VehicleFactory();
vehicleObject.getSummary();
vehicleObject.HayloFactory(firstname, lastname, phone, nbrVehicles, nbrTanks);
```

You're calling `getSummary` before you call `HayloFactory` - so it's trying to *display* the values in the object before you've *set* them to useful values.

Additionally, all your `calcXyz` methods are introducing new local variables, like this:

```
public void calcTotal(){
    double total = subtotal + tax;
}
```

Instead, they should be setting the *field* values:

```
public void calcTotal(){
    total = subtotal + tax;
}
```

If you change all of your calculation methods appropriately, then move the `getSummary()` call to the very end, it will work. (It's not quite how I'd have written the code, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 0):

The variables defined insides your methods have local scope only for example
 
        `double manufactureCost = nbrVehicles * VEHICLE_PRICE;`  
it actually hides your class variable `manufactureCost` .. 
they should be instead used as 
 `manufactureCost = nbrVehicles * VEHICLE_PRICE;`   
This way you can actually set the class variable which in turn displayed inside your `getSummary` method